# Best practices for storing kubernetes configuration in source control

Tags: git, configuration, kubernetes

In several places on the Kubernetes documentation site they recommend that you store your configuration YAML files inside source control for easy version-tracking, rollback, and deployment.

My colleagues and I are currently in the process of trying to decide on the structure of our git repository.

- We have decided that since configuration can change without any changes to the app code, that we would like to store configurations in a separate, shared repository.
- We may need multiple versions of some components running side-by-side within a given environment (cluster). These versions may have different configurations.

There seem to be a lot of potential variations, and all of them have shortcomings. What is the accepted way to structure such a repository?

Comment: We had the problem that developers kept forgetting to push their configuration changes so I built [autoapply](https://github.com/pascalgn/autoapply), which basically runs `git pull && kubectl apply` in a loop. It's not very polished, but you might be interested in the basic idea.

Comment: user315902 - Hi the autoapply looks cool. One question though. If my docker images are tagged using commit id.. how do i update helm chart to use that commit id, and push it before i have the commit id? I suppose similar problem is another number.. like build id.. probably less of a problem but I would have to go to build server to check next build id and hope nobody else checks in right? Using :latest is out of the question as explained on the kubernetes best practises. Any tips??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [helm](https://helm.sh) is going to become the standardized way to create an application installer for kubernetes clusters. I'll try to create my own [chart](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/create-your-first-helm-chart/) to parametrize my app deployments.

Comment: Helm seems to be a bit overkill for a microservice. Usually only a few variables like image tag, replicas change and the rest stays the same. Helm would be the appropriate approach if you want to package a bundle of the application for your customers or the community.

Comment: helm is an overkill for a microservice, but that wasn't the question. @kir was asking about how to separate deploy config for several components aka microservices, probably related, and for several environments.
 
In that case, even helm could show some shortcomings, now probable Operators are the right solution https://coreos.com/operators/

Answer (score 17):

There is no established standard yet, I believe. I find helm's charts too complicated to start with, especially having another unmanaged component running on the k8s cluster. This is a workflow that we follow that works quite well for a setup of 15ish microservices, and 5 different environments (devx2, staging, qa, prod).

The 2 key ideas:

1. Store kubernetes configurations in the same source repo that has the
   other build tooling. Eg: alongside the microservice source code which has the tooling for building/releasing that particular microservice.
2. Template the kubernetes configuration with something like jinja and render the templates according to the environment you're targeting.

The tooling is reasonably straightforward to figure out by putting together a few bash scripts or integrating with a Makefile etc.

EDIT: to answer some of the questions in the comment

The application source code repository is used as the single source of truth. So that means that if everything works as it should, changes should never be moved from the kubernetes cluster to the repository.

Changes directly on the server are prohibited in our workflow. If it ever does happen, we have to manually make sure they enter the application repository again.

Again, just want to note that the configurations stored in the source code are actually templates and use [`secretKeyRef`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) quite liberally. This means that some configurations are coming in from the CI tooling as they are rendered and some are coming in from secrets that live only on the cluster (like database passwords, API tokens etc.).

Comment: So you're storing your templates (as well as the code to render them) in the same source as the application? We were concerned about this approach because it meant that if there is a configuration change that needs to happen after a gold build is generated, you effectively have to go back and revision your code(if you have CI). 

Is this simply not a problem for you, or do you have a way around this? Is your application's copy of those configurations considered the source of truth, or do you propagate live changes (ad hoc kubectl edit/apply operations) back to the app source?

Comment: @kir Given how much Kubernetes resources can have a material impact on your application (a contrived example would be a init container that runs database migrations, or pod resources being too low), as a non-answer to your question, I'd want to do go through the gold process again if I made changes to the templates.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion Helm is to kubernetes as Docker-compose is to docker

There is no reason to fear helm, as in it's most basic functionality, all it does is similar to `kubectl apply -f templates`.

Once you get familiar with helm you can start using `values.yaml` and adding values into your kubernetes templates for maximum flexibility.

values.yaml

`name: my-name`

inside templates/deployment.yaml

`name: {{ .Values.name }}`

https://helm.sh/

Here are some approaches to using helm "infrastructure as code". Regardless of which approach you use, remember that you can also maintain a helm repository to distribute helm charts.

1. Create a helm subdirectory in each project, the same way that you may include a docker-compose.yml file.
2. Create a seperate helm repository for each chart and control it individually from the application code. This may be a better approach when code and infrastructure are managed by seperate teams.
3. Store all helm charts in a central repository. This is useful for easily distributing your charts, but may cause confusion when many teams are working on different charts.
4. If you want to have the benefits of method 3, with the clear ownership of method 2, you can use method 2 and instead create a git repo of submodules that pull from multiple chart repos which are maintained by appropriate owners.

Answer (score 5):

Google has built a tool to help with k8s development: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold. It suggests ways to store information for reuse by team mates/CI/etc.

There is also a Terraform Kubernetes provider, which allows you to keep your whole Kubernetes configuration as Terraform config files: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs. If you already use Terraform or other Hashicorp tools, this may be a good option.

Answer (score 4):

Use a separate repository to store configuration.

If you have multiple microservices to orchestrate, none of them is authoritative over the configuration- especially when you run multiple configurations in parallel, e.g. for canary testing.

Helm (https://helm.sh/) helps you propagate constants through multiple microservices' configurations. Again, this indicates that those constants / parameters are independent of any single codebase.