# Why should I store kubernetes deployment configuration into source control if kubernetes already keeps track of it?

Tags: kubernetes

One of the documented best practices for Kubernetes is to store the configuration in version control. It is mentioned in [the official best practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#general-configuration-tips) and also summed up in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168381/best-practices-for-storing-kubernetes-configuration-in-source-control) Stack Overflow question. The reason is that this is supposed to speed-up rollbacks if necessary.

My question is, why do we need to store this configuration if this is already stored by Kubernetes and there are ways with which we can easily [go back to a previous version of the configuration using for example kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment)? An example is a command like:

```
kubectl rollout history deployment/nginx-deployment
```

Isn't storing the configuration an unnecessary duplication of a piece of information that we will then have to keep synchronized?

The reason I am asking this is that we are building a configuration service on top of Kubernetes. The user will interact with it to configure multiple deployments, I was wondering if we should keep a history of the Kubernetes configuration and the content of configMaps in a database for possible roll backs or if we should just rely on kubernetes to retrieve the current configuration and rolling back to previous versions of the configuration.

Comment: Configuration as code is the goal. You want to be able to review, test, lint, track, tag, release, etc. your configuration. You also want a single source of truth, which is the set of files in front of you, not the collection of configurations Kubernetes has stored.

Comment: But if the system will automatically adapt to load, hardware failures, etc. then the actual configuration might be different than the one we specified, right? I wonder if the single source of truth is Kubernetes itself or the config files stored in the repository.

Comment: I mean, what happens if the entire cluster goes down? Or if you want to spin up another exact replica but a different environment? Having it in code makes it alot easier.

Comment: @Perennialista: Consider this workflow: someone wants to change some configuration parameter to X. They send a code review for this change, where normal review can happen, it is submitted, so now the intent is stored, some system decides when a safe deploy window is (e.g., during business hours), when that window comes it pushes the configuration to Kubernetes, and Kubernetes takes it from there. How do you get this same level of control and audibility if that original change was made directly to Kubernetes? I'm not saying you _can't_ use Kubernetes directly, I'm asking why would you want to?

Comment: @GManNickG: You are right, you provided a use case that gives some more reasons why somebody would want to keep configuration into source control. I was asking because, as mentioned at the end of my question, we are building a "configuration service" on top of kubernetes to allow the user to deploy our system without the need to deal with Kubernetes concepts. This discussion makes me think that I should store the configuration the user specifies.I am just worried that, should the user modify this configuration, he would modify a configuration that does not reflect the real state of the system.

Comment: Keep in mind there is no such thing as configuration that reflects the real state of the system. It's not possible to transactionally commit a change to configuration that instantly reflects itself in the real state. It always takes time for things to start, things may restart, etc. Configuration is always _intent_, and in this view a user modifying files is fine because they are merely changing what they intend to be. It's up to some other system to see this intent and make it so.

Comment: @GManNickG I really like this last comment you made, that clarifies and justifies storing the configuration. Feel free to write a short answer to the question if you have time so that I can accept it. If not I guess I'll wait another little bit and then add the answer myself?

Comment: @Perennialista: Sure thing, I'll have time to write a better answer sometime in the next day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use Kubernetes as your store of configuration, to your point, it's just that you probably shouldn't want to. By storing configuration as code, you get several benefits:

- Configuration changes get regular code reviews.
- They get versioned, are diffable, etc.
- They can be tested, linted, and whatever else you desired.
- They can be refactored, share code, and be documented.
- And all this happens *before* actually being pushed to Kubernetes.

That may seem bad ("but then my configuration is out of date!"), but keep in mind that configuration is actually never in date - just because you told Kubernetes you want 3 replicas running doesn't mean there are, or if there were that 1 isn't temporarily down right now, and so on.

Configuration expresses **intent**. It takes a different process to actually notice when your intent changes or doesn't match reality, and make it so. For Kubernetes, that storage is etcd and it's up to the master to, in a loop forever, ensure the stored intent matches reality. For you, the storage is source control and whatever process you want, automated or not, can, in a loop forever, ensure your code eventually becomes reflected in Kubernetes.

The rollback command, then, is just a very fast shortcut to "please do this *right now*!". It's for when your configuration intent was wrong and you don't have time to fix it. As soon as you roll back, you should chase your configuration and update it there as well. In a sense, this is indeed duplication, but it's a rare event compared to the normal flow, and the overall benefits outweigh this downside.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes cluster doesn't store your configuration it runs it, as you server runs your application code.